# Get protocol and domain from string in VB.Net

Tags: regex, vb.net, dns

how can I get the protocol and the domain form a string?

I think I should use regex for this?

Is this correct or is there a better solution?

If this is correct what should the regex code look like?

E.g.

I have the following URL: http://www.somedomain.com/page/subpage

And I would like to get: http://www.somedomain.com

Some more example URL's: https://www.somedomain.com/page/subpage (https://www.somedomain.com) or http://somedomain.com/page/subpage (http://somedomain.com) or http://test.domain.com/page/subpage (http://test.domain.com)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with:

```
Dim myUri as new Uri("http://www.somedomain.com/page/subpage")
```

and myUri will have all the answers for you. Domain property, protocol property etc etc. Off the top of my head, I think you need this:

```
Dim baseUri as String = myUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
```

-Oisin